# Javascript PHP/MySQL - Insert row value from database into textfield

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Possibly very easy to do but I cannot work it out!

I'm trying to make a button which inserts row value pulled out from the database into a textfield.

```
<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { ?> <tr> 
<td><?php echo $row['mobile_number']; ?></td>
<td><input type="button" value="select" onclick="clickMe()" /></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>

<input type="text" id="textfield" />
```

so when the button "select" is clicked, the textfield would get populated with the mobile number.

Many thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something: `<input type="text" id="textfield" value="<?php echo $row['mobile_number']; ?>" />` ?

Comment: @AmalMurali That would be instant instead of on click

Comment: Use jquery using .on method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script>
function clickMe(number) {
    document.getElementById("textfield").value = number;
    // or jQuery
    $("#textfield").val(number);
}
</script>

<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { ?> <tr> 
<td><?php echo $row['mobile_number']; ?></td>
<td><input type="button" value="select" onclick="clickMe(<?php echo $row['mobile_number']; ?>)" /></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>

<input type="text" id="textfield" />
```

Comment: Thank you so much!
document.getElementById("textfield").text = number; didn't work but the jQuery one did, any idea why?

Comment: Yeah I think it should be .value  Happy to help.

Comment: thanks, yes, .value worked! i've just tried this with another column which the values hold a string, e.g. "AB214" and it's not pulling the information now, does .val only pull integers?

Comment: YOu could try converting it to a string before you set it. number.toString()

Comment: Like this?: function clickMe2(text) {
    text.toString().$("#txtfield").val(text);
} -- it's not working :(

Comment: $("#textfield").val(number.toString());  Not sure that is it though. Sounds like a different problem.  Post another question about that issue.

Comment: didn't work, thank you though, i've posted a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19785737/php-mysql-javascript-insert-row-value-pulled-from-database-into-textfield-with