# PHP/MYSQL Javascript - Insert row value pulled from database into textfield with a button

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql

Im pulling out table information from a mysql db:

I need the buttons to select the information shown into a textfield, the below code works perfectly for the mobile_number but does not work for serial_number. both field types are varchars.

**php to pull out info and html button**

```
<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { ?>
<td><?php echo $row['serial_number']; ?><input type="button" value="select" onclick="button(<?php echo $row['serial_number']; ?>)" /></td>
<td><?php echo $row['mobile_number']; ?><input type="button" value="select" onclick="button1(<?php echo $row['mobile_number']; ?>)" /></td>
```

**text fields**

```
<input type="text" id="textfield"/>
<input type="text" id="textfield2"/>
```

**JS for the buttons**

```
function button(text) {
     $("#textfield").val(text);
}
function button1(number) {
     $("#textfield2").val(number);
}
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: You should avoid using `mysql_`functions — they have been deprecated.

Comment: Thank you Terry, are there any good manuals on this and how to update the code?

Comment: You should look into migrating your code over to `mysqli_` functions ([see here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)), or [PDO](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should wrap text inside quotes, e.g.

```
onclick="button('<?php echo $row['serial_number']; ?>')"
```

Same for mobile (it works probably only because it's a number)

Answer (score 1):

I would check if the column names being returned are the same as the ones you are referencing. Apart from that, use quotes, like @sebapalus suggested, and use the improved functions `sqli`